# I am getting error while moving file to NAS path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application to upload file. Application first store file to local server and then move to NAS path. Application is using System.IO.File.Move method of C# to move file from local server to NAS.
I am seeing strange issue. After login to application first upload works fine. but if upload another file immediately,it fails. If I wait for 3-5 minutes after a file upload and try to upload file again. it works.

I have tested the connectivity from local server to NAS, it is fine.

Same web application was running on another server, we have stopped application on that server and moved to this server. This issue is happening only on new server not on old server.

Error message:`The specified network name is no longer available.`

Line of code which throw error: `File.Move(sourceFilePath,DestinationFilePath)`

Also I was trying to see if connection to NAS path has issue. So what I did is that just before the line of code which is throwing error I added a condition:
`If(!File.Exist(DestinationFilePath)){ throw new Exception(<some message>)`

After adding this check application is working fine. I am not sure how?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "Any suggestion where is the issue." ...somewhere in code your probably. Or possibly in your config, or in the server config, or in the network, or in the NAS, or possibly somewhere in a black hole out in space. Since you provided us with pretty much zero information, it's impossible to say. We'd like to help you, but we are not mind-readers. Nor do we have secret access to your server. Unless you want us to continue guessing at random, please provide some relevant code, config information, and a better definition of "it fails"...e.g. error messages, exceptions, other debugging results. Thanks

Comment: N.B. Since you say this issue only arose when moving the application from one server to another, I would suggest a great place to start would be by comparing differences in the environment, config, network topology etc between the two servers. If you made no changes to the code at that time, then it's less likely that the code is the issue (although not impossible, if it does something unusual or not recommended, which the new server doesn't like).

Comment: @Adyson error which is get is "The specified network name is no longer available.".  Line of code which throw error is System.IO.File.Move(sourcefilename, destinationfilename). Added more information to question.